# Unable to marshall request to JSON, Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, android, gson

I am using amazon aws sns for push notification on android, everything works correctly and I am able to send and receive the notifications on my phone (lollipop os), while when I install the app on a device with (jellybean os), the app crashes when I am calling this

`CreatePlatformEndpointResult result = pushClient.createPlatformEndpoint(cpeReq);`

The error says `Unable to marshall request to JSON` and `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter`

I included the `gson` library but the problem persists.

**EDIT:**

I resolved this by using the latest gcm library 8.4.0 in my case and upgrading gradle to 2.10

Comment: You should post your edit as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using the latest gcm library 8.4.0 in my case and upgrading gradle to 2.10